# Can butan-1-ol be written as butanol, and is it connected to butan-1-ol having Isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can **butan-1-ol** be written as **butanol**, and is it connected to **butan-1-ol** having Isomers?

Comment: Depends where you are writing it. There's a difference between butan-1-ol and butan-2-ol. If you are describing something where that difference is important then you cannot just write butanol.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's convention to write butan-1-ol as butanol, just as it's likely to write propan-1-ol as propanol (whenever it's attached to the first carbon, we usually just omit the 1)

I'm not quite sure about what you mean with isomers, but we name isomers in different ways so that we can distinguish them. For example, butan-1-ol and butan-2-ol are considered to be positional isomers (same functional group, same carbon skeleton, but the functional group OH is attached to different carbons on these two different isomers) and we use the number to distinguish between them. Hope this makes sense?